# How do you dynamically set a layout for a Jade template to extend in Node.js/Express 3.0?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have 3 files: layoutA.jade, layoutB.jade and index.jade.  How can I programmatically set which layout that index.jade will extend?

I've tried using:

```
app.set('view options', { layout: false });
```

with:

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express', layout: 'layoutB' });  // older 2.x way?
```

I can't seem to override anything set explicitly in the index.jade file.  Omitting the extends line inside the index.jade file didn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets say the jade files are in the following directory:

```
+ views
  + shared
    - layoutA.jade
    - layoutB.jade
  + home
    - index.jade
```

Add the layout settings in the correct order, and specify the root views folder:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', { layout: 'shared/layoutA' });
```

Make sure you specify the correct folder(in this case 'views'). Also make sure to specify a valid default layout.  Check that this works with a test page before you dive deeper.

Once that is working you can the default layout like this:

```
if(someImportantVar) {
  res.render('home/index', { title: 'Different layout!', layout: 'shared/layoutB' });
} else {
  res.render('home/index', { title: 'Default layout!'});
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this solution is not right anymore, is it?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger As per the question title it should be correct for Express 3.0. Does it not work within that version?

Comment: I don't think there would be compatibility issue regarding `express 3` vs current `express 4.x` but on the jade-side : Using `pug 2.0`, I can tell that the `view options` parameter is not used anymore (or I'd be happy to be wrong). Been through a lot of searches to achieve dynamic layout in jade/pug without success, so this answer has been frustrating to me, despite not being wrong.